# Whats wrong with my java interpreter?

Tags: java, compilation, classpath, interpreter

I have a problem with a simple hello world program getting ran in the command prompt.  My CLASSPATH environment variable to set to the bin directory of my most recent java which i believe is 1.8.0_45.  There is no errors in the code that I know of:

```
public class helloWorld{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

The file name is helloWorld.java and I can compile the file without error.  When I type "java helloWorld" in the command prompt though it says it cannot find or load main class helloWorld.class.  I dunno what else could be wrong with it.  I could compile and run java files at one point in time but I think the only thing that changed was that java updated which I don't know if that changed the CLASSPATH variable but I just recent it to my most recent java which is the only one provided I believe if the installation happens properly.  If anyone can give me some pointers it would be very helpful.

Comment: The classpath is the set of directories where Java will look for Java classes. Don't set it to the `bin` directory of your JRE because there aren't any classes there!

Comment: Also, are you putting `helloWorld` inside of a package? If you have a `package a.b.c` line then you have to run it as `java a.b.c.helloWorld`

Comment: Classes should start with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the classpath when running java:

```
java -cp someClassPath helloWorld
```

Since your code does not specify a package, the class is compiled to the default package.  To run it, start inside the directory where `helloWorld.class` is located and execute `java` with the current directory as the classpath:

```
java -cp . helloWorld
```